# Phonegap - Determine exact element active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I need to change the back button functionality of my phonegap project, which I've succeeded in doing without any problem. The only issue now, is that I need to further change the functionality based on if the user has a certain field selected.

Basically, if the user has clicked in a field with the id of "date-selector1", I need to completely disable the back button.

I was attempting to use document.activeElement, but it only returns the type of the element (input in this case), but I still want the functionality to work when they are in a general input, but not when they are in an input of a specific id.

**EDIT**
I tried all of the suggestions below, and have ended up with the following code, but still no success.

```
function pluginDeviceReady() {
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

function onBackKeyDown() {
    var sElement = document.activeElement;
    var isBadElement = false;
    var eList = ['procedure-date', 'immunization-date', 'lab-test-done', 'condition-onset', 'condition-resolution', 'medication-start-date', 'medication-stop-date', 'reaction-date'];
   console.log("[[ACTIVE ELEMENT: --> " + document.activeElement + "]]");
   for (var i = 0;i < eList.length - 1;i++) {
        if (sElement == $(eList[i])[0]) {
            isBadElement = true;
        }
    }
    if (isBadElement) {
        console.log('Back button not allowed here');
    } else if ($.mobile.activePage.is('#main') || $.mobile.activePage.is('#family') || $.mobile.activePage.is('#login')) {
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    } else {
        navigator.app.backHistory();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're listening for the back button you can add this if statement:

```
if (document.activeElement == $("#date-selector1")[0]) { 
    /*disable button here, return false etc...*/ 
}
```

or even better (Thanks to Jonathan Sampson)

```
if (document.activeElement.id === "date-selector1") { 
    /*disable button here, return false etc...*/ 
}
```

Comment: How would that work though? Won't document.activeElement simply return [Object HTMLInputElement]? And it would do so for all inputs, not just a specific ID's?

Comment: Running document.activeElement in my console while I have this textbox selected returns <textarea name=​"comment" cols=​"68" rows=​"3">​</textarea>​ so: the whole element, attributes and all - just like $('#theID')[0] does. So I can match them

Comment: @ColbyRMeier `[Object HTMLInputElement]` means it has a reference to an input element on the page. It's not referring to just *any* input element, but a specific one. Because `document.activeElement` is referring to an input, you could call `document.activeElement.id` to get the `id` of that input if you wanted.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Thank you so much. The only issue I was missing was the .id on the end. I feel so stupid sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a flag set when a user clicks on a field or you can have a click event (or any other type of event) when a user clicks on the field that should disable the back button.

From the documentation it looks like for the specific page that the backbuton is conditional on you can drop `back-btn=true` removing that back button.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html

If you need complex conditional functionality you can just create your own button in the header or footer, style it using jquery-mobile widgets and implement your own click functionality.

Comment: Kind of what I was looking for, but I need to be able to find the id of the active element for said conditional statement.

Comment: @ColbyRMeier updated answer, why can't you just have an event that removes the back button when a certain action happens? whethere it is a click swipe focus or w/e?